# Const correctness and boost::serialization::make_binary_object

Tags: c++, boost, const-correctness

I am working on a piece of code that uses boost serialization to persist state. Having a class that has a const_char* member, I looked around to discover that make_binary_object would suit my needs. However, while I prefer splitting my code into save and load for const correctness of the rest of my code, I see that Boost's make_binary_object doesn't have a version that takes in a const_char*. Is there something that I am missing that suits my needs cleanly, short of resorting to a const_cast?

Comment: I don't really understand the use of the `const char *` in your code: if it's a pointer to a constant C string, then the object does not own it, so why save it with the object?

Comment: Yep...right. That's the code that I'm trying to work with -- and I'd not like make too many changes, if possible. I've split the serialization and deserialization to write a const char* and read into an owned object so that mem operations are handled correctly for the deserialized object. But, the serialization code makes use of the const char* member that is passed into it, and thus has non-onwing semantics -- perhaps that's code smell and I should be wrapping the const char* data into a owning object before serializing, but I'd like to prevent an extra deep copy during the serialization.

Comment: I don't know if there's a design issue there. The problem of forcing a const to a non const is that it's undefined behaviour. `make_binary_object` as I understand it is used both for serialization and deserialization, hence the non const requirement. I would probably try to make a separate class to deal specifically with `const char *` in your code, assuming that they are used quite a lot, and with some sharing.